# Should I always need to use cflock with SESSION scope variables?

Tags: session, coldfusion, locking, coldfusion-9

I have a simple Form , which on submission sets a variable in SESSION like

```
<cfset SESSION.shownote = 1>
```

After firing an confirmation Email to the user , I am just deleting this variable from the Session.

```
<cfset structdelete(SESSION,"shownote")>
```

Do I really need to user cflock in this case ? I can not think of a Race condition here.

As SESSION varies from one user to another , Can anyone please suggest me exactly on which situation we should use cflock with session variables?

I have also heard that, CF9 and CF10 automatically handles session locking , is it true?

Comment: Not related to your question, but does this session variable get used for anything?

Comment: No i have just given an example for reference

Answer (score 4):

A bit of googling probably could have had you answer your own question here, I think.

But, anyway, I wrote this up on my blog a while back: "[Question: when to lock scopes](http://blog.adamcameron.me/2013/04/question-when-to-lock-scopes.html)".

The bottom line is that there's no intrinsic need to lock the session scope (since CFMX 6.0), however - as with any code - one should ensure not to create race conditions in one's code, and sensible use of locking mitigates this.

Comment: "there's no intrinsic need to lock the session scope"  Is this documented somewhere in CF 9 or 10?

Comment: Come on mate, do some of your own work. The very first google result for "coldfusion session scope" is a link to the official docs where it's discussed.

Comment: Downvoted your answer here. It is highly recommended to use locking on any write operation since anything may end up in some kind of unexpected state. Adobe carries the chapters about the whole locking and deadlocks for a reason. People tend to ignore such "negligible things" and screw up big time, even if it's just "that one case".

Comment: Feel free to downvote me, but you're talking ballocks based on decade-out-of-date information. But it's no odds to me. Adobe's *own* guidance - the one I mention two comments above this one - makes it clear what you're saying is out of date, and states that the considerations to watch for since CF moved to Java are simply those of race conditions. Session writes are synchronised, so they are intrinsically safe outside of race conditions.

Comment: Adam, here's the #2 result for `cflock session variables`: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c48.html which specifically states "Important: Always put code that accesses session variables inside cflock tags." This question, BTW, is now the #1 google hit. Google results change all the time, and different documentation says different things. In fact the top result contradicts your assertion. I realize this is a year later and an older version of CF, but still.

Comment: @JordanReiter what can I say? The docs aren't written by very clued-up people, and they probably aren't aware of the changes made to the architecture of the session scope between CF5 and CFMX6 which makes this advice... well... *bad*. Session scope access is *already* locked by Java, as it's synchronised. Oh wait... I already said that in the article I linked to above, so there's no point saying it again. [shrug]

Comment: @AdamCameron sorry. My point wasn't clear. I'm not arguing whether or not you need to use the lock or not. Rather that in this case Google is not necessarily presenting a quick and straightforward answer. You asserted that had Deepak "done his own work"  he would find that the first hit on Google addressed this issue in a straightforward manner and clearly it doesn't. While I agree that expecting people to Google for you is a bit annoying, I personally find it more annoying when people get on other people's cases about it. [shrug]

Comment: @JordanReiter: I'm with ya. The problem with most people (and Deepak is a good example here) is that they simply *haven't* done any research for themselves first. You make a point that google results might contradict themselves, but it's vital for ppl to actually do the research first. Had Deepak said "I've read [the doc you pointed to], and it contradicts itself [it does], so I'm confused", that's far more helpful for everyone. Here's my thoughts on documenting research: http://blog.adamcameron.me/2012/12/need-help-know-how-to-ask-for-it.html#google

Answer (score 3):

If your application needs to check for the existence of SESSION.shownote or the value of SESSION.shownote, then you have a race condition and should use cflock.

Although your example did not include any such checks, presumably developers do no set variables for no reason. Let's say that your form processing script checks for the existence of SESSION.shownote and *conditionally* sends a confirmation e-mail if that condition is true.

I'll demonstrate the race condition. Let's say a user has 2 browser windows open to your example form. Both share the same session, and the forms are submitted at the same time. We'll call these submissions ONE and TWO.

Processing could happen like this, which causes no problems:

1. ONE sets SESSION.shownote = 1
2. ONE checks for SESSION.shownote. It exists; send e-mail
3. ONE deletes SESSION.shownote.
4. TWO sets SESSION.shownote = 1
5. TWO checks for SESSION.shownote. It exists; send e-mail
6. TWO deletes SESSION.shownote.

But it could happen like this, which is a problem:

1. ONE sets SESSION.shownote = 1
2. TWO sets SESSION.shownote = 1
3. ONE checks for SESSION.shownote. It exists; send e-mail
4. ONE deletes SESSION.shownote.
5. TWO checks for SESSION.shownote. It does **not** exists; do **not** send e-mail

In this case, not locking the session scope has caused unexpected behavior.

Comment: So this means when ever we declare/modify value of some session variables in a .cfm, we need to use cflock always?